# Не работает remove jquery

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему элементы не удаляются.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".items").remove(".element");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".items .element").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
</div>
```